# redirect non www to www in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to redirect to www using wordpress management system (not through htaccess).
I can not seem to find it under settings -> general.

Here is the screen:

[image]

And here is my top menu

[image]

Comment: What version of wp you are using ?

Comment: Where can I check this? It's the first time i'm using WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like you are Using **WordPress Network** site because of that the Option for URL is not available on that screen

for this case you have to Manage All this options from the **Network admin** and **Network Setup** section

Please take a look over the snap for the Network admin part 
[image]

Comment: And where I can find it? I have no those options in the menu.

Comment: Please take a look i have added Screens for the same but you must be Network admin to do so

Comment: Yes!! in wordpress.com, and I have no Plugin menu too.

Comment: yes in wordpress.com you will be having very limited access..... i guess it will be batter to post your Question here http://en.forums.wordpress.com/ this is the Best place to get help for the Wordpress.com......

Comment: as the above solutions will work if you have your own WordPress Network site